# Unique Identifier of an individual event in the system log?

Tags: windows-7, windows, event-log, event-viewer

I searched for a specific Event ID ([6008 Unexpected Shutdown](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/21d4a698-103a-4e1b-9ad8-915633c76af9)) in the Windows 7 Event Viewer, but now I want to see the events in the log that led up to that event, so how can I search for that specific event as it appears in the log with the logs before and after it?

Is there some sort of primary key I can search for, or is it more unstructured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will probably have to do multiple searches, the first by Event ID, and then by time range, to get the preceding messages. there is no linkage between messages, so there isn't a good way to get related messages, except by time span.

Comment: Wow thanks Microsoft!  A Binary format that doesn't have any primary keys!  No wonder it's so hard to diagnose issues on Windows.